# Prevent resizing on Show()

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Form containing a user control
The following properties are set on the form

```
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Inherit;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(640, 236);
        this.ControlBox = false;
        this.Controls.Add(this.progressControl);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(6);
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(666, 307);
        this.MinimizeBox = false;
        this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(666, 307);
        this.Name = "SimpleProgressForm2Levels";
        this.ShowIcon = false;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Text = "SimpleProgressForm2Levels";
```

When calling the Show() method, the window is resized and it looks ugly (in particular for the height). I am using .Net Framework 4.6.2.

Does anyone know how to prevent this automatic resizing?

Comment: of course it is resizing... the clientsize is not inside the minimum/maximum range...

Comment: Do not edit designer-generated code yourself.  That is how accidents like AutoScaleMode.Inherit and the invalid ClientSize vs Min/MaximumSize happen.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `AutoScaleMode` to  `None`:

```
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.None;
```

This will prevent windows from messing with your form size.

Comment: Your clientSize is a different value then the values you specify for MaximumSize and MinimumSize. Try to use the same value for all 3 properties.

Comment: Still not changing anything. Normally client size is for the content of the form  and automatically calculated by visual studio

Comment: Well, I'm running out of ideas here. Hope someone else will be able to help. Sorry....

Comment: Thanks for trying ;)